# Dictionary with two keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

What is the best way to index value by two keys in a dictionary. Ex.: having students with unique Id(integer) and username(string) create a dictionary that holds objects of type student indexed by Id and username. Then on a retrieval use either Id or username.
Or may be Dictionary is not a good match?
P.S. I'm aware of tuples but failing to see how they can be used in this scenario.

EDIT: As an alternative to using two keys, I could create a string representation of both id and username separated by unique divider, and then match keys using regex?! Ex.: "1625|user1"

Comment: is username also unique or not?

Comment: `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<int,Student>>` property of that type should work as you need

Comment: yes, unique in "unique Id(integer) and username(string)" referred to both

Comment: If you go for @harry180's comment, I'd recommend creating a new class to abstract this complexity. I've seen them get out of control before, like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<int,string>>>`. It just makes it more maintainable and you can switch without affecting existing code

Comment: @Dimitri: so ID (int) isn't unique across students?

Comment: @Dominic - both, Id and username are unique across...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to be able to retrieve by either, you'll need two dictionaries.

Assuming the `Student` type is a reference type, you'll still only have one `Student` object per student, so don't worry about that.

It would be best to wrap the dictionaries in a single object:

```
public class StudentDictionary
{
  private readonly Dictionary<int, Student> _byId = new Dictionary<int, Student>();
  private readonly Dictionary<string, Student> _byUsername = new Dictionary<string, Student>();//use appropriate `IEqualityComparer<string>` if you want other than ordinal string match
  public void Add(Student student)
  {
    _byId[student.ID] = student;
    _byUsername[student.Username] = student;
  }
  public bool TryGetValue(int id, out Student student)
  {
    return _byId.TryGetValue(id, out student);
  }
  public bool TryGetValue(string username, out Student student)
  {
    return _byUsername.TryGetValue(username, out student);
  }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Awesome. Looks like the answer to me

Comment: It's possible to build a lighter double-key dictionary, but hard to justify the considerable extra effort.

Comment: Yeah i see this definitely working for me and quite enough for my needs. Thanks alot

Comment: And you want to introduce "indexers" to your class like this: `public Student this[int id] { get { return _byId[id]; } }` and also `public Student this[string username] { get { return _byUsername[username]; } }`. Because it's cool. They are used like so: `studDict[1336654]` or `studDict["jeppesn"]` where `studDict` is some `StudentDictionary` object.

Comment: The one thing about the indexers, is that you don't want setters on them, because this dictionary is managing its own key->value relationships.

Comment: @Joey, but what if I try to add student number 3 under id 2? I could trap the error, but better just to force the single route (after all, whenever I have an id and a student, I have a student, so there's no case an index caters for that the adder doesn't).

Comment: @Jon - To make the above Dictionary implementation a thread-safe, would you just replace private Dictionary objects with ConcurrentDictionary objects or implement a statick syncRoot object and lock on it each time you add/take from dictionary?

Comment: 1. I'd go with a lock before I'd go with ConcurrentDictionary in this case, because you need to check on all the cases where you do something after you've added to one internal dictionary but not yet the second. 2. If I'd have heavy contention then the next thing I'd do is reason all the cases to work out if two `ConcurrentDictionary` fields would work - it might, indeed I'm pretty sure it would - but you have to do the work to reason out the transitions, and you can't do it with starting code but above because you need to think about all the members you add to the above...

Comment: ... 3. Failing that, I'd build my own low-lock thread-safe dictionary, but that's easier for me to say as someone whose built a low-lock thread-safe dictionary before. I'd hate to have to do it with a deadline!

Comment: Hmm. Indeed, considering it, if I had to make this low-lock I wouldn't take the approach I did with that one, I'd use striped locking like `ConcurrentDictionary` does.

Comment: An alternative appoach could be to have just one single backing dictionary (or `SortedList<int, Student>` maybe). Then access by the other key (username) would require a linear search through the entire inner collection. This is very easy to code (e.g. LINQ's `.Single(Func<Student, bool>)` method) but of course performs only O(n). But maybe it's easy to get thread safety with that.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen if anything there's greater dependency between the two for correctness, so I'd worry it would be actually harder to get thread-safety.

Comment: @JonHanna Between what two? If you only have a `private readonly Dictionary<int, Student> _dict` inside your class `StudentDictionary`, and not anything else, then that's one collection less. But you will have to say `_dict.Values.Single(s => s.Username == username)` to lookup with a `username` string.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen oh sorry, I misread. It gains nothing in the locking approach, and will fail in the `ConcurrentDictionary` approach as enumerating values is thread-safe as in it lets you enumerate over the values as they change, but not as in promising you wouldn't see a change as a removal.

Comment: Would add some error checking.  If ID was unique but not UserName the two dictionaries would get out of synch.

Answer (score 3):

You can use two dictionaries you keep in sync, one that maps names to students, and another that maps IDs to students. The easiest way is probably to wrap that in your own class which handles the synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

No, a `Tuple` helped you only if you always had both `Id` and `Username`. You could either use a `Dictionaries` for each key. You could also implement your own `Dictionary` which enables you to query for both keys, given their type is different:

```
class MyDictionary : IDictionary<int, Student>, IDictionary<string, Student> {
    // full implementation
}
```

Comment: how would i check if a key is in the dictionary?
MyDictionary.Keys.Contains(178) || MyDictionary.Keys.Contains("User2") ?

Comment: Jon came up with a neat implementation. It would be `MyDictionary`'s responsibility to keep both inner dictionaries in sync (so they'd both contain the very same set of students), therefore you'd only have to check `178` or `User2`.

Comment: yep, thanks a lot. upvoted your answer for an elegant approach

Answer (score 0):

Using the student object is a good option for what you want but you would have to override the equality functions (Equals and GetHashCode) for it to work properly.

EDIT after reading this part more carefully "Then on a retrieval use either Id or username" I think my answer is not the best way.  I would go with two dictionaries so +1 to @JonHanna.

Comment: would you mind expanding this answer? I fail to see what `GetHashCode` has to do with anything.

Comment: I'm not using student object as a key, just value

Comment: Just to clarify about GethashCode, it is always a bad idea to implement a custom Equals without a matching custom GetHashCode as sometimes the hashcode is used to test for equality. This could be "cross contamination" from coding in Java, but I think it still applies as a good general rule.

Comment: And upon further research it turns out that the dictionary in c# (just like just all other hash table implementations) uses the hashcode for internal indexing and retrieval.

Comment: True on the gethashcode. Incidentally, I mention `IEqualityComparer<string>` in my answer. That gives a custom equals and gethashcode for a custom purpose (with .NET providing several string-related cases out of the box).